# Set up Phalcon 3.0.x with Php 7.0.x in ubuntu16.04

Tags: php, installation, phalcon, php-7, ubuntu-16.04

My first question is , is Phalcon 3.0.x compatible with php 7.0.x and is it recomended? Phalcon documentation says Phalcon 3.0 does so (with zephir).
My other question is 
How to set up Phalcon with php 7 in ubuntu?
Can any one tell the proper way, becacuse this involves some configurations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, Phalcon 3.0.x is fully compatible with PHP 7.0.x. And it is highly recommended that you use it with PHP 7.

You can easily install Phalcon 3 on Ubuntu. The install proces is rather easy now. It is possible to just download the already compiled version of Phalcon.

```
curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/phalcon/stable/script.deb.sh | sudo bash

# Ubuntu 16.04+ or Debian 9+
sudo apt-get install php7.0-phalcon
```

**One of the alternative ways** to install Phalcon is by compiling it yourself.

```
# download the required packages
sudo apt-get install php5-dev php5-mysql gcc libpcre3-dev

# download and compile the Phalcon repository
git clone --depth=1 git://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon.git
cd cphalcon/build
sudo ./install
```

Don't forget to add the Phalcon extension at the bottom of your php.ini file or even better, create a new `phalcon.so` file in your module folder (with the following content):

```
extension=phalcon.so
```

Have a look at the [installation documentation](https://phalconphp.com/download) for the latest install information.

Comment: Thanks Timothy..One more thing to clarify.

Comment: git clone --depth=1 git://github.com/phalcon/cphalcon.git
cd cphalcon/build
sudo ./install Does the compilation part needed to use Phalcon 3.0?

Comment: That command is used to compile phalcon yourself. It isn't needed if you just install the Phalcon package. See my updated answer